# Shade background of a ggplot chart using geom_rect with categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my dataset example:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("group1","group2","group3", "group4", "group5", "group6"), each=3),
                 X = paste(letters[1:18]),
                 Y = c(1:18))
```

As you can see, there are three variables, two of them categorical (`group` and `X`). I have constructed a line chart using ggplot2 where the X axis is `X` and Y axis is `Y`.

I want to shade the background using the `group` variable, so that 6 different colors must appear.

I tried this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 0, xmax = 3, ymin = -0.5, ymax = Inf,
            fill = 'blue', alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5)
```

But `geom_rect()` only colorize the area between `0` and `3`, in the X axis.

I guess I can do it manually by replicating the the `geom_rect()` so many times as groups I have. But I am sure there must be a more beautiful code using the variable itself. Any idea?

Answer (score 14):

To get shading for the entire graph, `geom_rect` needs the `xmin` and `xmax` locations for all the rectangles, so these need to be provided by mapping `xmin` and `xmax` to columns in the data, rather than hard-coding them.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = X, xmax = dplyr::lead(X), ymin = -0.5, ymax = Inf, fill = group), 
            alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(Xn=as.numeric(X))

ggplot(df2) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=Xn-.5, xmax=Xn+.5, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill = group), alpha=0.5, stat="identity") +
  geom_point(aes(x = Xn, y = Y), size = 2.5) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=df2$Xn, labels=df2$X)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will get you close - need to add a couple columns to your data frame. Using dplyr here.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(xmin = sort(X)[1],
         xmax = sort(X, decreasing = T)[1])

ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=xmin, xmax = xmax, fill = group), ymin = -0.5, ymax = Inf,
            alpha = 0.05)
```