# How to use geom_rect() based on different y value?

Tags: r

I have the following example data where I'm trying to plot `var1` using `geom_jitter()` and would like to shade the background multiple colours with `geom_rect()` based on `t_score`. I'm trying to replicate this method which was presented [elsewhere](https://twitter.com/Duhigs/status/1564951447850156033?s=20&t=8pUqzB41uSkBW8bOwDQEcA) where I'm preserving the *y* axis as the **raw** value (`var1`) but shading the background based on the **standardised** (`t_score`) value. I created a separate column in my data (`rect_colour`) with the colours I'd like for certain values, but I'm not sure if this is thr right approach or not. Some help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)

dat <- data.frame(
  
  var1 = round(rnorm(100, 0.200, 0.400), 3),
  label = rep("Category 1", times = 100)
  
  )

dat$var1_scaled <- scale(dat$var1)
dat$t_score <- round( ( dat$var1_scaled * 10 ) + 50)

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(rect_colour = case_when(t_score > 80 ~ "darkgreen",
                                 t_score >= 46 & t_score <= 79 ~ "white",
                                 t_score >= 40 & t_score <= 45 ~ "orange",
                                 t_score >= 30 & t_score <= 39 ~ "lightred",
                                 t_score >= 20 & t_score <= 29 ~ "red",
                                 t_score < 20 ~ "darkred"))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = label, y = var1)) +
  geom_jitter(size = 4, alpha = 0.5, width = 0.15)
```

Comment: I needed to run `dat$var1_scaled <- as.numeric(scale(dat$var1))` to make `var1_scaled` be a vector so that later steps would work.

Comment: What color is "lightred"? I don't believe that one is in the R standard named colors.

Comment: Worked for me if I added `color = rect_colour` to the `aes()` and then `+  scale_color_identity()`, in the sense that then the dots were shaded as specified.

Comment: Are you looking for a variation of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50339909/shade-background-of-a-ggplot-chart-using-geom-rect-with-categorical-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `geom_rect` to draw the background areas, each with its color. To do this, summarise the data computing values for `ymin` and `ymax`.

Color `"lightred"` doesn't exist as you  can see with function `colors()`. From its documentation:

> Description
> Returns the built-in color names which R knows about.

```r
colors() |> grep("red$", x = _, value = TRUE)
#> [1] "darkred"         "indianred"       "mediumvioletred" "orangered"      
#> [5] "palevioletred"   "red"             "violetred"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I have substituted `"orangered"` for `"lightred"`.
(Note the new pipe operator introduced in R 4.1 and the new placeholder introduced in R 4.2.)

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
)

set.seed(10)

dat <- data.frame(
  var1 = round(rnorm(100, 0.200, 0.400), 3),
  label = rep("Category 1", times = 100)
)

colors_vec <- c("darkgreen", "white", "orange", "orangered", "red", "darkred")
colors_vec <- setNames(colors_vec, colors_vec)

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(var1_scaled = scale(var1),
         t_score = round( ( var1_scaled * 10 ) + 50)) %>%
  mutate(rect_colour = case_when(t_score > 80 ~ "darkgreen",
                                 t_score >= 46 & t_score <= 79 ~ "white",
                                 t_score >= 40 & t_score <= 45 ~ "orange",
                                 t_score >= 30 & t_score <= 39 ~ "orangered",
                                 t_score >= 20 & t_score <= 29 ~ "red",
                                 t_score < 20 ~ "darkred"))

dat_rect <- dat %>%
  group_by(label, rect_colour) %>%
  summarise(ymin = min(var1), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  arrange(ymin) %>%
  mutate(ymax = lead(ymin, default = Inf))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = label, y = var1)) +
  geom_rect(data = dat_rect,
            mapping = aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax,
                          fill = rect_colour, colour = rect_colour),
            xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
            inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_jitter(size = 4, alpha = 0.5, width = 0.15) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors_vec) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors_vec)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>